# gulp-pug: compile new on changed files only (case with "includes" and "extends")

Tags: gulp, pug, gulp-watch

Consider the following file system:

pug

test1.pug

test2.pug

partials

partial1.pug

With gulp task

```
gulp.task('pug', () => {
  return gulp.src('pug/*.pug')
  .pipe(pug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

even we edit only **test1.pug**, both **test1.pug** and **test2.pug** will be compiled. If to change task to

```
gulp.task('pug', () => {
  return gulp.src('pug/*.pug', {since: gulp.lastRun('pug')})
  .pipe(pug())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

since second 'pug' running by **gulp-watch**, changed or new files only will be passed. However, what if the `partial1.pug` has been included to `test1.pug`? (Assume that `gulp.watch` observes  all files).

**test1.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Test 1
  body
    h1 Test 1
    include partials/partial1.pug
```

If we edit **test1.pug**, of course it will be compiled. However if we edit **partial1.pug**, test1.pug will not be passed by `{since: gulp.lastRun('pug')}`.

I don't know, how to solve this problem, but I suppose, we need to filter assembled pug from files or already compiled html but before output. If it is possible...

### Update

Maybe I did not explained clearly the desired result. We need:

- **test1.pug** has beed edited → compile **test1.pug** only
- **partial1.pug** has beed edited → compile **test1.pug** only
- **test2.pug** has beed edited → compile **test2.pug** only

Let me repeat that **partial1.pug** include in **test1.pug** but not to **test2.pug**.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies outside of the `src` pattern are not available at this stage to be watched. They are added later down the pipe (by `pug()`).
To support your use case, Gulp would need to have a way to gather dependencies from downstream transformers. For the moment this falls outside of the scope of Gulp (this is a complex behavior with many possible design choices).

The best solution to your issue is to manually update your `src` pattern to match your whole dependency tree. In your case it would be `pub/**/*.pug`. (The wildstar `**` allows you to match files in any subdirectory).

You may also take a look at implementing [your own watcher](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb) to get finer control (I fear that my pattern above may emit HTML even for your partials).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, if I change pattern to `pug/**/*.pug`, **partial1.pug** will be compiled to separate file. Unlike gulp-sass, which do not compile files begins from `_`, **pug** cannot detect partial files. So, currently I assume that we place entry points in the first level under **pug** folder, and below it - partial files. Is some compromise exists?

Comment: I was effectively thinking about this issue in the last sentence of my answer. I think that the best for you would be to keep your original `pug` task but add another task with `gulp.watch("pug/**/*.pug", "pug")`. So your task will only compile your root files but watch all the pug files.

Comment: Am sorry about skipping your last sentence. Your solution is exactly what I do for now. What unacceptably is files that has not been changed compiles again (bad for performance). E. g. if I edit **partial1.pug** from the example in question, assembled **test1.pug** will change, but **test2.pug** will not. However, both  **test1.pug** and **test2.pug** will be compiled. If we use `since: gulp.lastRun`, even **gulp.watch("pug/**/*.pug", "pug")** will not help: as separate file **test1.pug** has not been changed, so `gulp.lastRun` will not pass it.

Comment: Maybe I did not explained clearly the desired result. I updated the question field.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am not aware of how to achieve your goal at the moment. It seems to require support from Pug or gulp-pug. It's a good question, I'll reply to you if I find an answer.

Comment: Thank you too for your time. [I have try](https://github.com/gulp-community/gulp-pug/issues/182) to ask same question on GitHub, however has been rejected...